# Write array into cell

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, cell-array

I've been using Matlab for quite awhile but this one has got me--I want a one-liner that will take an array and write it into the indexed entries of a cell, e.g.

```
>> c = cell(1,6);
>> b = [1 2 3];
>> c{[2 4 6]} = b; %This doesn't actually work
>> disp(c)

   []  [1]  []  [2]  []  [3]
```

I've tried all sorts of versions of this with `num2cell`, `deal` et al. but I can't find the magic bullet.  Can it be done in a single assignment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `mat2cell` -

```
c([2 4 6]) = mat2cell(b,1,ones(1,numel(b)));
```

With `num2cell` -

```
c([2 4 6]) = num2cell(b);
```

Output -

```
>> disp(c)
    []    [1]    []    [2]    []    [3]
```

Comment: @MattPhillips Yup! That was missing there :)